# adjust width of jcombobox dropdown menu

Tags: java, jcombobox

Is there a way to adjust the drop-down window size of a JCombobox?

let's say I have:

```
comArmor.setBounds(81, 102, 194, 26);
```

But when the user selects the box and the drop-down list pops up, i'd like for the drop-down window to expand so that a long line of text will be displayed entirely (say size x of 300).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Small hack to get pop up menu size bigger enough to show items even though the combo box size could be smaller

Source: http://www.jroller.com/santhosh/entry/make_jcombobox_popup_wide_enough

```
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.util.Vector;

    import javax.swing.ComboBoxModel;
    import javax.swing.JComboBox;

    public class ComboBoxFullMenu<E> extends JComboBox<E> {

        public ComboBoxFullMenu(E[] items) {
            super(items);
            addActionListener(this);
        }

        public ComboBoxFullMenu(Vector<E> items) {
            super(items);
            addActionListener(this);
        }

        public ComboBoxFullMenu(ComboBoxModel<E> aModel) {
            super(aModel);
            addActionListener(this);
        }

        /**
         * Small hack to get pop up menu size bigger enough to show items even though
         * the combo box size could be smaller
         * */
        private boolean layingOut = false; 

        @Override
        public void doLayout(){ 
            try{ 
                layingOut = true; 
                super.doLayout(); 
            }finally{ 
                layingOut = false; 
            } 
        } 

        @Override
        public Dimension getSize(){ 
            Dimension dim = super.getSize(); 
            if ( !layingOut ) {
                dim.width = Math.max(dim.width, getPreferredSize().width);
            }
            return dim; 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is built in functionality for this already, but you could always have a `ActionListener` which listens for selection changes and then programmatically set the width of the `JComboBox` to the length of the selected content ([`getSelectedItem()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#getSelectedItem())) when it changes.

```
box.addActionListener (new ActionListener () {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String item = comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
        comboBox.setBounds(81, 102, item.length * CONSTANT, 26);
    }
});
```

It seems a bit hacky to me and you might have to play around with this idea to get it to work.

I hope this helps you!

**Update:**

JComboBox appears to have a [`setPrototypeDisplayValue(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setPrototypeDisplayValue(E)) method that is used to calculate component's preferred width based on the length of the parameter.

> Sets the prototype display value used to calculate the size of the display for the UI portion.

I might consider using this instead.